# My PC can't access to Internet while my other devices can

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking

My PC connects to the router through wifi and is set to automatically find IP and DNS. 
My PC tells me that it is connected, and, sometimes it says that it has Internet Access, and sometimes not.

My other devices (iPod and Android phone) are connected to the router and DO have access to internet.
In the router settings, in WAN section, it appears my ISP IP.
My PC isn't blocked by MAC filtering.

It isn't a DNS issue since I can't connect to the internet by IP or hostname.

I've tried with the firewall disabled.

I've reboot my PC a couple of times.

I've uninstall the drivers of my wireless card, and reinstalled it again.

Now it keeps showing me that it IS connected and does have internet access but can't access any website, only the router webserver.

EDIT: I've rebooted the router from the web server (because I don't have physical access to it) and worked just for 5 minutes!

EDIT 2: I've rebooted the router again and It worked but has just died again. I repeat that it only happens in my computer. I'm writing in my iPod connected to the same WLAN.

---

**EDIT 3:** I've solved it. I'm not sure why. A week ago I had enabled the Statistics on my Tp-link TL-WR941ND router, and I also had enabled DoS protection because I read this,

"Note: FLOOD Filtering will take effect only when the Traffic Statistics in System Tools is enabled."

so I thought I should had to enable that feature for security since I had just enabled Statistics.

Now, I've just disabled DoS protection and Statistics, and it started to work fine. Rare.

Besides that, I would like to keep using Statistics.

Comment: From the PC can you ping the router? Probably something like "ping 192.168.0.1" or 192.168.1.1

Comment: Also if you do "ipconfig" on the PC it will tell you if you have an IP given by the router. It should be 192.168.x.x if properly addressed.

Comment: Yes. I've just tried it. I even can access to the web server settings

Comment: Yes. It was assigned by the dhcp server.

Comment: I've rebooted the router again and It worked but has just died again. I repeat that it only happens in my computer. I'm writing in my iPod connected to the same WLAN

Answer (score 0):

I have already seen such behavior in an older PC and the conclusion was that is was caused by a hardware failure. If I remember well it was a wifi 802.11G USB dongle and after connecting it was working for a couple of minutes then failing. I had to have it cool a little bit while disconnected and then I was good for another couple minutes.

So I don't know if it is an internal wifi card or not but you could try another one if possible.

Comment: I second this. I also had my share of network problems, which where ultimately caused by hardware or driver failure. Since you've already tried the drivers (are you sure they are compatible with your OS btw?) i think your best chance is to check another network card and see if the problem persists

Comment: It's a Tp-Link PCI wireless card. Since I wa trying to solve this problem I uninstalled the original one and installed the generic windows one called Atheros AR9287 Wireless Network Adapter